# How can I get sbt to not "add anything extra" to println output?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a utility that uses `println`.
I want to do `sbt 'runMain com.foo.bar.Main'` and see only what I `println`ed: no `[info]` prefix on all the messages, and no front matter saying "welcome to sbt", "loading", etc. etc.

I'm looking to specify this option on the command line, as an argument to sbt, without changing anything in build.sbt. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sbt -batch -error 'runMain com.foo.bar.Main'
```

`-batch` tells sbt that you don't want to start any kind of interactive session, and `-error` limits all logging to errors only.

Comment: This is helpful, but not what I was looking for. I want to still see `println`s from my program, but `-error` means I don't see those. If I do just `-batch` I still see `[info]` prefixes for the things I `println`. Is there a way to have sbt not mess with the stdio at all and see exactly what I'd see if I ran from a jar?

Comment: On my system I see `println`s without `[info]`.

Comment: Which sbt version? I'm on  1.4.7

Comment: @MaxHeiber launcher version 1.5.5, and build.properties version 1.5.1

Comment: This answer works for me on sbt 1.5.5. Any "println" in the main class come out without [info] prefixes

Comment: Didn't have a chance to try it yet, but accepting because the bounty is about to expire. Thanks for your answer.